# Adding GDAL as dependency to Python package?

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to package a Python script that uses GDAL for PyPI. I started by including a direct reference in my `setup.py`:

`install_requires=['GDAL==1.11.2'],`

This way the package failed to install in my test virtual environment:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2855:22: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cpl_port.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I then tried it with a reference to `pygdal`, since it is marked as a virtualenv friendly version:

`install_requires=['pygdal'],`

This way the installation finishes without errors (but with the usual load of compilation warnings). However, when then I invoke the script I get this error back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/desouslu/.virtualenvs/test_p3/bin/hasc2gml", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/desouslu/.virtualenvs/test_p3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2716, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/desouslu/.virtualenvs/test_p3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 685, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/desouslu/.virtualenvs/test_p3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pygdal
```

What is the correct way of setting GDAL as a dependency?

**Update**: The dependency seems to be correctly declared, the problem is likely upstream, with the GDAL package itself. Further details at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471683/how-to-add-gdal-as-a-dependency-to-a-python-package).

Comment: It is a pure Python question

Comment: I would argue that a pure Python question about gdal is valid here.

Comment: Interesting how the reviewers seem so certain this a strictly Python question but have so far abstained from pointing what it is.

Comment: It is a python and GDAL question and I think on topic

Comment: This was cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471683/how-to-add-gdal-as-a-dependency-to-a-python-package

Comment: @EvilGenius I normally downvote cross-postings but in this instance I can condone it because the original close voting on the question here indicated that was the way to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Before installing GDAL python binding, you must install GDAL on your system.

```
apt-get install -y libgdal-dev
```

After that, set variables and install binding

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal \
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal \
pip install GDAL
```

Version of the system GDAL should be higher than the version bindings.